# jQuery in Firefox: letters missing in script-populated text area

Tags: jquery, firefox, text

I've looked all over for an answer to this, but can't find a thing, so please forgive me if my google fu is lacking.

I have an online resume with a portion that flashes customer kudos for 5 seconds each. I use jQuery to fade out the div, update the text from the next kudos and fade back in. It works perfectly in Chrome. In Firefox, however, every instance of the string "st" is left out. In other words, "frustrating" is rendered as "frurating," "best" is rendered as "be" and "customer" is rendered as "cuomer." Interesting to note that that console log shows the correct text in Firefox.

In Chrome:

[image: Has ST]

In Firefox:

[image: Missing ST]

JS:

```
function runKudosSlideshow() {
var numkudos = $('.kudosquote').length;
var kudostext = [];
var kudosheight;
var kudosmargin;
var thiskudos;
var i;
var j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numkudos; i++){
    kudostext[i] = $('.kudosquote').eq(i).text();
}
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(kudostext[j]);
    thiskudos = kudostext[j];
    $('#thekudos').animate({opacity:0},500, function(){
        $('#thekudos').text(thiskudos);
        kudosheight = $('#akudos').height();
        kudosmargin = (10 + (40 - (kudosheight / 2)));
        $('#akudos').css('margin-top',kudosmargin);
        $('#thekudos').animate({opacity:1},500);
    });
    j++;
    if (j >= numkudos){
        j = 0;
    }
}, 5000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="akudos">
    <span id="thekudos">
        CUSTOMER PRAISE....
    </span>
</div>
<div id="quotes">
    <p class="kudosquote">This was the best service I've had all day!</p>
    <p class="kudosquote">The best</p>
    <p class="kudosquote">The best</p>
    <p class="kudosquote">The best</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#akudos{
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    width:650px;
    margin-top:35px;
    z-index:100;
}
.kudosquote{
    display:none;
}
#kudos{
    position:absolute;
    top:170px;
    left:0;
    width:820px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:90;
    background:-o-prefix-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(200,200,200,.8) 50%, rgba(200,200,200,.6) 80%, rgba(200,200,200,.25));
    background:-moz-prefix-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(200,200,200,.8) 50%, rgba(200,200,200,.6) 80%, rgba(200,200,200,.25));
    background:-prefix-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(200,200,200,.8) 50%, rgba(200,200,200,.6) 80%, rgba(200,200,200,.25));
    background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(200,200,200,.8) 50%, rgba(200,200,200,.6) 80%, rgba(200,200,200,.25));
}
#thekudos{
    font-family:'Radley', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#3E3E87;  
}
```

Comment: Works fine in FF here. Where do you call the function? I'm guessing that this is related to the custom font you've picked. Have you tried others?

Comment: David, yes mo frurating. 
@j08691 Could it be the addons I'm using in FF?

Comment: Sure. Tried starting FF without them?

Comment: If you view the text in View Source or F12 dev tools, are those characters present?

Comment: Dave, yes it does. @j08691 I disabled the font in the FF F12 Inspector and the "st"s all showed up. So I guess your first thought about the font was correct. Any suggestions for keeping a nice font but avoiding this issue?

Comment: I tried several fonts available from Google and they all showed the "st"s. The resolution was to not use Radley font and use another one, in my case, Libre Baskerville was a nice substitution.